# White blank screen when I try to use AuthProvider and useAuth (react + firebase)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, material-ui

I'm trying to set up my firebase authorization but keep running into the same problem.  I'm not sure why, but for some reason, I get a white blank screen whenever I put AuthProvider around my components, my router, anything.  As soon as I comment it out, my login and register pages pop back up again.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've gone through my code for hours and can't find the issue.  I'm hoping it's something small that I'm missing, but really hope someone can help.

Also, I'm using Material-UI (though I doubt that makes a difference) and I have all of my API keys and such in a .env file (I have 3x checked that they're all correct).

Anyway, here's my authentication.js code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import app from "./firebase";

export const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
    const [pending, setPending] = useState(true);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        app.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            setCurrentUser(user)
            setPending(false)
        });
    }, []);

    if(pending){
        return <>Please wait...</>
        }
    return (
    
    <AuthContext.Provider
        value={{
        currentUser
        }}
    >
        {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

I also tried this way in my context folder:

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { auth } from '../firebase';

const AuthContext = React.createContext()

export function useAuth(){
    return useContext(AuthContext)
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null)
    
    function register(email, password) {
        return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            setCurrentUser(user)
        })

        return unsubscribe
    }, [])
    
    
    const value = {
        currentUser,
        register
    }
    
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

And here's my App.js code:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'fontsource-roboto';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './Home';
import Login from './Login';
import Register from './Register'
// import { AuthProvider } from '../authentication';

function App(){
    return (
        // <AuthProvider>
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                    <Route exact path="/Register" component={Register} />
                </div>
            </Router>
        // </AuthProvider>
    )
}

export default App;
```

And my Register page if that helps:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
// import { Alert } from '@material-ui/lab';

import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
// import { useAuth } from '../contexts/AuthContext';
// import register from '../contexts/AuthContext'

function Copyright() {
    return (
        <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" align="center">
        {'Copyright © '}
        <Link color="inherit" href="https://kindredcompanion.app/">
          Kindred Companion App
        </Link>{' '}
        {new Date().getFullYear()}
        {'.'}
      </Typography>
    );
  }

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    height: '100vh',
  },
  image: {
    // VTM Banner
    backgroundImage: 'url(https://res.cloudinary.com/think-halcyon-llc/image/upload/v1617055998/Vampire:%20the%20Masquerade/vtm_banner_qze9dn.png)',
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    backgroundColor:
      theme.palette.type === 'light' ? theme.palette.grey[50] : theme.palette.grey[900],
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    backgroundPosition: 'center',
  },
  paper: {
    margin: theme.spacing(8, 4),
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  avatar: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
  form: {
    width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  submit: {
    margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
  },
}));

export default function Register() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  
  const firstNameRef = useRef()
  const lastNameRef = useRef()
  const emailRef = useRef()
  const passwordRef = useRef()
  const passwordConfirmRef = useRef()
  
//   const { register } = useAuth()
//   const [error, setError] = useState("")
//   const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

//   async function handleSubmit(e) {
//       e.preventDefault()

//       if (passwordRef.current.value !== passwordConfirmRef.current.value) {
//           return setError("Passwords do not match.")
//       }

//       try {
//           setError("")
//           setLoading(true)
//           await register(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value)
//       } catch {
//           setError("Failed to create an account.")
//       }

//       setLoading(false)
//   }
  
  return (
    <Grid container component="main" className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Grid item xs={false} sm={4} md={7} className={classes.image} />
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={8} md={5} component={Paper} elevation={6} square>
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Register
        </Typography>
        <br />
        {/* {error && <Alert severity="error">{error}</Alert>} */}
        <form 
            className={classes.form} 
            // onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        >
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <TextField
                autoComplete="fname"
                name="firstName"
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="firstName"
                label="First Name"
                inputRef={firstNameRef}
                autoFocus
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="lastName"
                label="Last Name"
                name="lastName"
                inputRef={lastNameRef}
                autoComplete="lname"
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="email"
                label="Email Address"
                name="email"
                inputRef={emailRef}
                autoComplete="email"
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                name="password"
                label="Password"
                type="password"
                id="password"
                inputRef={passwordRef}
                autoComplete="current-password"
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                name="password-confirm"
                label="Password Confirmation"
                type="password"
                id="password"
                inputRef={passwordConfirmRef}
                autoComplete="current-password"
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
            // disabled={loading}
          >
            Sign Up
          </Button>
          <Grid container justify="flex-end">
            <Grid item>
              <Link href="/login" variant="body2">
                Already have an account? Sign in
              </Link>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Box mt={5}>
              <Copyright />
          </Box>
        </form>
      </div>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Hoping someone can help me!

Comment: Does it show a completely blank page or does it show a blank page with `Please wait...` text?

Comment: You get the currentUser even before your Login and Register route ?

Comment: @NearHuscarl It shows a completely blank page.  It's odd.

Comment: @VoQuocThang I was partway through setting up authentication when the screen went blank.  The routes work on their own tho.

Answer (score 1):

I actually had this issue too. My .env file was configured wrong and Firebase threw me an error where it said Invalid API key. Hopefully this helps!